# hyperlinkfield error with gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that contains 4 columns (id, name, address , and a button in each line )
what I want is that when I click the button, another page is displayed (called profile.aspx) automatically displaying the id automatically
I used hyperlinkfield but nothing happens, no changes in the profile page

Here is my code

```
<asp:HyperLinkField Text="Traiter" HeaderText="Traitement" DataNavigateUrlFields="id" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="profile.aspx" />
```

Comment: Check out [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx). The page you go to will need the appropriate code to *use* the `id` that you pass to it.

Comment: I changed the code according to the article, now the error is
The literal content ('<asp: HyperLinkField ...) is not allowed in a' System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection '.

Comment: Someone else jump in on this if possible.